# Python String function rstrip() not working

Tags: python, string

I have a string `sentence` that contains trailing punctuation that I want to remove. To do this I'm passing a string parameter `punctuation` to my function `remove_punc` that contains the trailing punctuation that I want to remove:

```
def remove_punc(sentence, punctuation):
   """takes input parameters sentence (type string) and 
   punctuation (type string), and returns a string that 
   strips all trailing punctuations in sentence."""
```

I have tried `sentence.rstrip(punctuation)` for the example:

```
remove_punc("This is some, and \"I\" know it is a long one!", "?!.,")
```

However this returns:

```
'This is some, and "I" know it is a long one'
```

The expected output is:

```
'This is some and "I" know it is a long one'
```

Am I using `rstrip()` incorrectly?

Comment: rstrip() works on trailing characters. In your example, the comma that you expect to be removed (after the word 'some') is not a trailing character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lstrip` only removes the characters if they're at the beginning (left) of the string, `rstrip` only removes the characters if they're at the end (right) of the string, while `strip` is a combination of both `lstrip` and `rstrip`. To solve your problem, you'd should look into [`string.replace()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp) or [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

```
def remove_punc(sentence, punctuation):
    for punc in punctuation:
        sentence = sentence.replace(punc, '')
    return sentence
```

or

```
import re
def remove_punc(sentence, punctuation):
    punctuation = '[' + punctuation + ']'
    return re.sub(punctuation, '', sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.rstrip` and `.strip` remove from the beginning and end of a string. They don't effect the middle. For that you should use, `.replace` or something similar.